# How can I set an or-require in a rpm spec-file?

Tags: rpmbuild

I am trying to create an rpm. It is possible set requires in the spec-file:

Requires: package a when package b is not installed

Comment: Please read the RPM documentation http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Docs and then come back with a more specific query of what you have tried  and what has failed.

Comment: Thx.i found it, but only for v4.13. I have 4.8 and i can not update. It is not allowed.

Comment: The principles for 4.13 are similar to 4.8; and in any case, you can look at the documentation for older versions at that exact same site.